# Promote documents with file names that contain the keyword search to the top

Tags: 2013, search, search-results, enterprise-search, promoted-results

For our enterprise search, we would like to promote any documents that has a file name that contains the word being searched to the top.  As of right now, it doesn't appear to do this.  Instead, it seems to sort based on the number of times that word appears in a document.

Is there a simple way to fix this so that if I were to say, search for "adjustment", that all documents containing the word "adjustment" would appear at the top?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not done this yet, but you can do it in SEVERAL ways depending on the results you seek.

1. Create a Query Rule that will "Change ranked results by changing the query". Create a query for `{?Title:{searchTerms}}`
2. Another technique is to use XRANK and Content Boost to change the query for example: `{searchTerms} XRANK(cb=100) {?Title:{searchTerms}}` would elevate the matching titles with a content boost of 100.

The topic of relevance tuning in SharePoint is VERY deep. Before you do too much tweaking you should let SharePoint run for a while to learn your users and content. If you want to learn more about these topics check out Mikael's blog at http://techmikael.blogspot.com/

Comment: Matthew, could you be more specific with creating the rule?  Would the query condition be an Advanced Query Text Match and would I put the `{?Title:{searchTerms}}` in the "Query matches this regular expression" textbox?

Comment: You'll have to play with it depending on your requirements and how you want the results. Each of my examples would be the Query. Since you are matching every query you just delete the condition.

Comment: This is Keyword Query Language.  You can check out the book by Mikael: http://www.bookdepository.com/Sharepoint-Search-Queries-Explained-Mikael-Svenson/9781505887037